# Issue using self-signed SAML2 cetificate

Tags: certificate, saml-2.0

As a service providor, we need to support login using a Id-providor by SAML2. For this purpose we need to create a self-signed certificate.

For test purposes I have created one using:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=SAML2Test" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -FriendlyName "SAML2Test" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

But when trying to generate our meta-data for submitting to the Id-providor, an exception happens in a third party SAML library (.net)

```
if (certificate.HasCngKey())
{
    CngKey key = certificate.GetCngPrivateKey(); // BREAKS HERE
    Security.Cryptography.RSACng rsa = new Security.Cryptography.RSACng(key);
    rsa.EncryptionPaddingMode = AsymmetricPaddingMode.Pkcs1;
    SigningKey = rsa;
}
else
{
    SigningKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
}
```

The exception is

> An exception of type
> 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in
> Security.Cryptography.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> The keys do not exist

I do not know what a CNG key is.

Any idea on how I progress from here?

Comment: Looks like the certificate you generated does not have a Private Key. Generate one with Key

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for it to not being able to get the private key. On the certificate, no rights were set for the IIS_IUSRS to access the private key.